# How can I customize the Visual Studio 2010 Start Page to show recent Websites?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, start-page

Is it possible to have the **Visual Studio 2010 Start Page** show a list of **Recent Websites** in addition to (or in place of) the list of **Recent Projects**?  Most of my solutions are Websites, and it's annoying that I have to go thru the `File > ...` menu for those when there's a Recent Projects list on the start page going unused.

Previous versions of VS showed Websites in the Recent... list, I don't know why they'd take that functionality out of the new one.

I tried simply replacing the `DataContext="{Binding RecentProjects}"` line with `DataContext="{Binding RecentWebsites}"`, but not surprisingly, that didn't work.

Comment: I remember that this was an issue when launching Visual Studio from a pinned taskbar shortcut. Are they still hidden when launching Visual Studio directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to chime in with the solution I found.

While I still don't know if it's possible to show the recent Websites on the *Start Page*, you can at least get the same effect.  Heres' how:

After you create a Website, *Visual Studio* creates a .SLN file in the "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects" directory.  So if you create a website named MyWeb in your WWWROOT folder (or anywhere else), *Visual Studio* will create "C:\Users\shughes.DOM\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyWeb\MyWeb.sln" for you.  You can then open that .SLN file, and it will open the site no different than if you had opened it with the **FILE > OPEN WEB SITE** menu option.  The solution will be added to the normal *Recent Projects* list and you can pin them and open them from the *Start Page*.

Hope that helps someone.. it's a little thing, but takes a few clicks out of my life every day, and that's enough for me. :)